# How to fill the polygons of the radar chart in ggradar in R

Tags: r, polygon, radar-chart

I'm plotting the radar chart using `ggradar` and I would like to fill the polygons of the chart with different colours. Does anyone know how to do this?

Also, how to remove the legend? I cannot remove the legend even thought I've added `plot.legend=FALSE`.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
ggradar(dg, group.point.size=1,
        axis.labels=c("Depression", "Stress", "Anxiety"), label.centre.y=FALSE, plot.legend=FALSE, values.radar =c("","",""))
```

Thanks very much!
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is it compulsory using `ggradar::ggradar()` or can you use also other packages/functions?

Comment: I've tried to use `radarchart` but I cannot save the image using `png(filename="radar.png")`. It is saved as a blank page. Actually I just need to plot radar chart and save out the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a `ggradar()` solution -[look here](https://github.com/ricardo-bion/ggradar/issues/13)-, but you can work with `ggplot()` an `ggiraphExtra()` packages (data are the famous iris dataset, due you did not provide any data):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraphExtra)

radar <- ggRadar(data=iris,aes(group=Species), alpha = 0.3) + # alpha for polygon colors intensity
         theme_light() +                                      # white background etc.
         theme(legend.position = 'none')                      # no legend
radar
```

[image]

You can tweak as you want. 
 
And you can save it:

```
ggsave(filename="radar.png")
```